# R, tbl_summary knitting to PDF with gtsummary

Tags: r, kableextra, gtsummary

I've been using tbl_summary from the gtsummary package to make tables for publication.  Well, and to share with less tech-savvy peers.  Ideally I'd love to knit my tables/data/r code into a pdf for sharing.  When I knit the below code to html (instead of pdf), it formats ok:

```
tbl_summary(
    trial12,
    by = was_there_a_drain_placed_a,
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)"), 
    missing = "no" # don't list missing data separately
  ) %>%
  add_overall()%>%
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**") %>% # update the column header
  bold_labels() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1", "stat_2") ~ "**Drain**")%>% add_p()
```

What it should look like:
[image]

But when I knit to PDF, the text is all left-aligned and not formatted well:

[image]

I'd run into formatting problems with tbl_summary knitting to pdf before, but when I added this snippet of code to other data and projects it worked well:

[image]

I got that snippet from here: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html

The problem is when I do that for this data, it comes out like this:

```
tbl_summary(
    trial12,
    by = was_there_a_drain_placed_a,
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)"), 
    missing = "no" # don't list missing data separately
  ) %>%
  add_overall()%>%
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**") %>% # update the column header
  bold_labels() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1", "stat_2") ~ "**Drain**")%>% add_p()%>%
  # convert to kableExtra
  as_kable_extra(booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  # reduce font size to make table fit. 
  # you may also use the `latex_options = "scale_down"` argument here.
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down")
```

[image]

With those weird underscores everywhere.

I've also tried:

```
    test<-tbl_summary(
    trial12,
    by = was_there_a_drain_placed_a,
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)"), 
    missing = "no" # don't list missing data separately
  ) %>%
  add_overall()%>%
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**") %>% # update the column header
  bold_labels() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1", "stat_2") ~ "**Drain**")%>% add_p()
  
  as_kable_extra(test,format="latex")
```

And it still has those underscores.

Help!  Is there a way I can turn my tables that I made using tbl_summary into something that looks halfway decent in a pdf?  Ideally I would continue to use tbl_summary.

If you'd like reproducible data:

```
trial12<-structure(list(gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = c("labelled", 
"factor"), label = "Gender"), Age = c(34.7479452054795, 54.5178082191781, 
55.6328767123288, 25.4328767123288, 25.5287671232877, 53.1041095890411, 
52.0821917808219, 49.5205479452055, 74.9698630136986, 24.2739726027397, 
34.2657534246575, 58.3095890410959, 21.827397260274, 19.572602739726, 
60.8602739726027, 47.1835616438356, 61.8164383561644, 18.9205479452055, 
56.6438356164384, 66.7780821917808, 41.9698630136986, 27.1095890410959, 
21.0109589041096, 18.0547945205479, 33.5506849315069, 44.0630136986301, 
46.0712328767123, 54.3095890410959, 58.8493150684931, 47.7643835616438, 
54.972602739726, 54.5260273972603, 63.3780821917808, 77.2438356164384, 
29.0301369863014, 21.5068493150685, 45.0328767123288, 55.6602739726027, 
57.7397260273973, 64.2191780821918, 41.4383561643836, 70.1890410958904, 
44.413698630137, 48.5753424657534, 45.5945205479452, 2.81643835616438, 
51.5424657534247, 52.6191780821918, 54.2684931506849, 54.0684931506849, 
67.0493150684931, 34.3917808219178, 55.1534246575342, 35.7232876712329, 
28.6082191780822, 48.9561643835616, 79.6164383561644), length_of_hospital_admissi = structure(c(4, 
8, 39, 43, 34, 18, 55, 14, 11, 58, 24, 16, 24, 43, 22, 59, 28, 
16, 10, 20, 23, 14, 80, 47, 58, 69, 12, 27, 18, 9, 10, 26, 8, 
11, 31, 17, 38, 13, 21, 12, 52, 24, 66, 17, 49, 6, 187, 34, 55, 
15, 19, 92, 50, 51, 6, 27, 37), label = "Length of Admission following Craniectomy", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), length_of_admission_follow = structure(c(1, 1, 2, 
3, 14, 5, 23, 2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 13, 
5, 8, 3, 3, 2, 1, 7, 3, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 49, 3, 3, 17, 10, 7, 9, 
2, 9, 3, 69, 3, 28, 2, 5, 60, 15, 21, 2, 2, 3), label = "Length of Hospital Admission Following Cranioplasty", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), reoperation_prior_to_crani = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Reoperation Prior to Craniectomy", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), how_long_was_the_craniopla = structure(c(170, 150, 
210, 220, 210, 155, 190, 225, 216, 210, 175, 215, 190, 160, 180, 
175, 390, 135, 195, 215, 230, 180, 190, 150, 215, 150, 180, 210, 
200, 265, NA, 180, 230, 210, 210, 210, 160, 150, 200, 149, 102, 
175, 182, 190, 190, 354, 210, 150, 175, 148, 175, 215, 190, 190, 
215, 295, 150), label = "How long was Cranioplasty in minutes", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), Smoke = structure(c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", NA, "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
"No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes"), label = "Smoking Status", class = c("labelled", 
"character")), tobacco_use_at_time_of_sur = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes", "Former"
), class = c("labelled", "factor"), label = "Tobacco Use at Time of Surgery"), 
    Time_To_Cranioplasty = structure(c(65, 7, 84, 193, 20, 167, 
    33, 201, 76, 120, 463, 103, 88, 101, 237, 56, 71, 79, 265, 
    191, 106, 101, 66, 105, 50, 410, 193, 60, 129, 99, 50, 84, 
    91, 76, 72, 116, 82, 65, 194, 27, 42, 77, 78, 97, 75, 95, 
    118, 90, 25, 65, 85, 32, 35, 30, 89, 103, 95), class = c("labelled", 
    "difftime"), units = "days", label = "Time to Cranioplasty in Days"), 
    did_complication_require_e = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
    NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = c("labelled", 
    "factor"), label = "Did Complication Require Explantation"), 
    was_there_a_drain_placed_a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No Drain Placed", 
    "Drain Placed"), class = "factor"), defect_circumference = c(33.48, 
    25.1, 38.04, 42.69, 43.14, 40.92, 44.76, 39.65, 41.47, 47.89, 
    47.11, 38.86, 47.23, 38.23, 39.2, 41.61, 39.83, 39.76, 42.53, 
    39.16, 43.98, 40.51, 44.19, 31.05, 43.29, 44.46, 39.07, 46.66, 
    34.67, 44.28, 42, 38.98, 37.01, 35.54, 32.16, 42.39, 41.41, 
    42.07, 39.26, 32.01, 39.54, 36.4, 47.22, 42, 56.73, 30.5, 
    43.41, 38.27, 39.27, 41.84, 39.68, 41.08, 39.4, 41.65, 47.78, 
    39.37, 41.62), if_yes_complications_what___1 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No Infection", 
    "Infection"), class = c("labelled", "factor"), label = "Infection"), 
    if_yes_complications_what___2 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Subgaleal/Subcutaenous Fluid Collection", class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), if_yes_complications_what___3 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No Resorption", 
    "Resorption"), class = c("labelled", "factor"), label = "Bone Flap Resorption"), 
    if_yes_complications_what___4 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Pseudomeningocele", class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), if_yes_complications_what___5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), if_yes_complications_what___6 = structure(c(1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Wound Dehiscence", class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), if_yes_complications_what___7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), if_yes_complications_what___8 = structure(c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Extra Axial Fluid Collection", class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), if_yes_complications_what___9 = structure(c(0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Reccurent CVA", class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), if_yes_complications_what___10 = structure(c(0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), label = "Seizure", class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), if_yes_complications_what___11 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), if_yes_complications_what___12 = structure(c(0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Hydrocephalus", class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), if_yes_complications_what___13 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), if_yes_complications_what___14 = structure(c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Hygroma", class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), if_yes_complications_what___15 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), if_yes_complications_what___16 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-57L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The underscores are markdown language to bold text. If you remove the `bold_labels()` call, they will go away. I am looking into the mis-placement of the spanning header in kableExtra now.....

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg  Thank you for looking into this! I didn't realize I'd get the man himself.  Sounds like the bold labels just won't work with pdf?  It'd be a shame to lose them

Comment: Among the output formats, kableExtra is the one I am the least familiar with.  If bold a cell is possible, I can update the printing code pretty easily to bold it

Comment: In the meantime, have you tried `as_flex_table()` or `as_hux_table()` for PDF output?

Comment: Haha, I'm less familiar with flex table and hux table respectively.  I just tried as_flex_table and it seemed to work formatting wise (bold in correct spots, indent still didn't work as everything was fully left) but spilled way off the page.  Something I usually corrected with kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down") for kable stuff.

Comment: I just posted a fix for the spanning header. It'll be reviewed soon, but you can install it now with `remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/gtsummary@kableExtra_spanning_bug")`. That should resolve the spanning header placement problem.

Comment: For bolding, it looks like you need to use `kableExtra::cell_spec()` on the data frame before it is passed to `knitr::kable()`. The issue is that you also need to specify the output format as this stage. I don't set the format...kable auto determines it, meaning that it would be tricky to implement on my side. If you want, you can add the bolding before you convert with kableExtra. The data frame that is being printed is `x$table_body` and you can directly modify it?

Comment: I think you'll have the most luck managing large tables in PDF using `as_hux_table()`. They export a proper latex table, so you'll have the entire family of latex formatting available to you.

Comment: `%>% as_gt()` seems to work, except the n(%) footnote appears way off to the left.